# Change to cell background colour depending on value in a different cell in New Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'd like to have the cell background colour change to green or red depending on what I type in the cell, and I would like this to be dependent on the cell above.

So if the A1 cell says 7 and I type 8 into A2 I want A2 to have a red background.

If the A1 cell  says 7 and I type 6 into A2  I want the background colour to change to green.

So, to recap, if A2 is less than or greater than A1, I want A2 to change to green or red. And I want to have this happening throughout the entire A column.

If A3 is higher or lower than A2 I want A3's background colour to change to red or green but I'm not bothered about A3 being higher or lower than A1, if you know what I mean? - I only want the cell to change colour based on the cell directly above it.

I am aware of conditional formatting and the option to use formula and also the <> options but I just can't seem to get it to work? I'm using the new Google spreadsheets.

Thanks In Advance
Philip.

Answer (score 9):

Nice that you mentioned, you are using new Google Spreadsheet.

```
Select A2
Format - Conditional Formatting
```

From the dropdown select `"Custom formula is"` and type `=A1<A2` tick `Background` and select the color red color. Change `Range` as requried.

Click +Add another rule

From the dropdown select `"Custom formula is"` and type `=A1>A2` tick `Background` and select the color green color. Change `Range` as in Rule 1.

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cQNFW_YK836qz0m51p62zwPwCV_X84FqQLiGyM8zEuw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks but this hasn't worked. Check out what's happening  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17iMXRnt5H1SkJyLcQx2QBpWzkrvypUPbuZ_ry9vmL3U/pubhtml  When the next value is greater than the preceding, it highlights the preceding value. I want it to highlight the higher value. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2so3jZAt9fhcUpQMHVVNDBsZW8/edit This is the conditional formatting I've used

Comment: Have you tried the spreadsheet link that I have attached, does it give correct or incorrect colour?

Comment: Your example doesn't let me edit it to try it for myself, but looking at it, the value that is higher than the one preceding it is colored red, which is what I wanted. A5 > A4 so A5 is red. Not sure then what I'm doing wrong within my own sheet?

Comment: Goto File - Make a copy and then you will get an edit access for the file, you can then follow the condt. formatting rules.

Comment: No it hasn't worked I'm afraid. It is highlighting but it is highlighting the cell above the cell that is higher. See example. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17iMXRnt5H1SkJyLcQx2QBpWzkrvypUPbuZ_ry9vmL3U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's the cell value 74 that should be highlighted, as that is an increase from cell value 72. However, for some reason it is highlighting 72.